# Using annotations to create multiple versions of an API

Tags: java, compiler-construction, annotations, preprocessor

Is it possible to use annotations to create multiple versions of an API?

I've got a target API that needs implementing, but it has grown in time, and I would like to support multiple levels - if possible in the same branch. I've already thought about splitting up the API and proxy it to implementation library, but that still requires a lot of code to keep synchronized.

So you would create code like:

```
@Since("1.2") <- only created when 1.2 or higher
public interface InNewerAPI {

    @Since("1.3") <- only compiled when 1.3 or higher
    public void methodInEvenNewerAPI();

}
```

Of course I could also use a preprocessor for this, but I would like to avoid pre-processors for Java code.

Are there any drawbacks to this approach (such as loosing argument names prior to 1.8)?

Note that I need support for interfaces and classes, including abstract and inner classes. Methods and constants need to be versioned as well.

Comment: i think this is elegant

Comment: You are talking about supporting multiple Java versions, not different versions of your API, correct?

Comment: How would you like to use these annotations? I mean do you want to prevent older clients to call newer API or prevent older client even to see it?

Comment: @KevinSheehan No, different versions of an API (that I did not specify), which contains both interfaces and classes.

Comment: @AlexR The latter, they should not be present in the class files (e.g. to avoid having clients build for the wrong system).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I think that you can really use annotations to mark ranges of versions that should expose the API. For example if method `foo()` was introduced in version 1.1. and deprecated in version 1.5 you can mark it as following:

class MyApiImpl {
    @Since("1.2")
    @DeprecateAt("1.4")
    @Until("1.5")
    foo();
}

Then you can automatically generate interface interface `MyApi` according to client version:

1. for client prior version 1.2 this method will not be included into the interface.
2. for client between versions 1.2 and 1.4 it will be included
3. for client version 1.4 it will be included but marked as `@Deprecated`
4. it will not be included for clients after 1.5